# Get more compatibly modes

Tags: windows, compatibility, addons, more

If your running windows and you hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> + **double click** on any application it opens up properties for that application. On shortcuts you can get **compatibility settings**.

[image: compatibility settings]

---

**My Question:**
 Is it possible to get more **Compatibility modes** maybe from  3rd party website or any other source

---

Comment: What other compatbility modes are you looking for exactly?  [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/133746/how-does-the-compatibility-mode-in-windows-work?rq=1) is some related information on this feature even works.

Comment: @Ramhound I am not looking for a specific mode  however on my old windows 7 computer windows 8 only programmes (not talking about the apps) could be useful. Thanks for the link.

Comment: If it runs on Windows 8, then it will run without compatbility mode, on Windows 7.  You can create your [own application shim](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/7/archive/2010/01/22/creating-an-application-compatibility-shim.aspx) if thats what your wondering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without 3rd party Software **The Answer is NO**.

The Program Compatibility have all legacy Microsoft OS Options Supported by your current Operating System, and for the [Legacy System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) it haves [WoW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_on_Windows)(Windows on Windows) for x86 and 16-bit Software.

Compatibility can't cross Platforms for Example:

```
Windows > Unix

Windows > OSX

Windows > Linux
```

That happen because the software is compiled to be executed by a diferent Kernel who works quite diferent.

With 3rd Party Software **The Answer is Yes partially** But not in the way as you are waiting for.

Some developers have made the way to execute programs compiled to be used in another plattform.

In Linux we haves [WINE](https://www.winehq.org/)

> Wine (originally an acronym for "Wine Is Not an Emulator") is a
>   compatibility layer capable of running Windows applications on several
>   POSIX-compliant operating systems, such as Linux, Mac OSX, & BSD.
>   Instead of simulating internal Windows logic like a virtual machine or
>   emulator, Wine translates Windows API calls into POSIX calls
>   on-the-fly, eliminating the performance and memory penalties of other
>   methods and allowing you to cleanly integrate Windows applications
>   into your desktop.
>
> Wine began in 1993 under the initial coordination of Bob Amstadt as a
>   way to support running Windows 3.1 programs on Linux. Very early on,
>   leadership over Wine's development passed to Alexandre Julliard, who
>   has managed the project ever since. Over the years, as the Windows API
>   and applications have evolved to take advantage of new hardware and
>   software, Wine has adapted to support new features, all while being
>   ported to other OSes, becoming more stable, and providing a better
>   user-experience.
>
> An ambitious project by definition, work on Wine would steadily
>   continue for 15 years before the program finally reached v1.0, the
>   first stable release, in 2008. Several releases later, Wine is still
>   under active development today, and although there is more work to be
>   done, millions of people are estimated to use Wine to run their
>   Windows software on the OS of their choice.

In Windows we have [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)

> Cygwin is:
>
> a large collection of GNU and Open Source tools which provide 
>   functionality similar to a Linux distribution on Windows.
>
> a DLL (cygwin1.dll) which provides substantial POSIX API functionality.

Anyway that 3rd party programs can't handle all software.

And remember Compatibility is Only For Legacy Products you cant have compatibility to a Highter S.O you can do a Workaround to make the software works, or maybe get a patch but not compabitibity as well.

Comment: @RACING121 you welcome.

Comment: The amount of typos and technical inaccuracies that exist in this answer, took an answer with potential, and just tossed it out the window.  If you improve the quality of this question I will reverse my vote.

Comment: @Ramhound I agree it took me some time understand