# program compatibility only works in test mode

Tags: compatibility, visual-studio

I had a bizarre issue with my code not working with a new version of a CAD software's API. It seemed to be fixed after running windows 10 program compatibility troubleshooter.https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/15078/windows-make-older-programs-compatible on visual studios.
The only issue is, it only works from running it through that and clicking the test program button. If i pick the "yes it worked save settings" option then close the visual studios that was launched through test and open it again as i normally would, i have the same old issue.
I thought i could try to manually make the changes that might be made but the program does not offer a "compatibility" tab in properties.
Any suggestion why this might be the case or better yet, how i can manually and permanently apply the fix that running it in test mode seems to.

Note: I left out details about the initial problem of it not working with the API as its probably not helpful. One exception might be that the compiled .exe visual studios produces does not work when created outside of vs launched by test, but it does work if you put it on the desktop folder. Put it on a sub-folder in the desktop or anywhere else and it breaks.

Comment: I am not clear on what your question is exactly.  If your wondering the reason it works, compatability mode uses shims.  So the problem could either exist in the API itself or Win32 framework, in either case, the shim is bypassing the bug in the code.

Comment: [How does the “Compatibility Mode” in Windows work?](http://superuser.com/questions/133746/how-does-the-compatibility-mode-in-windows-work)

Comment: A shim is executable specific.  This means each time you build the application, the shim, would have to be applied again.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Any suggestions on how to permanently open vs with the shim. FYI, if Visual Studios is opened in compatibility mode, the builds also work so i don't actually change anything on the build itself.

Comment: If you can determine which shim actually works you can create your own shim and apply the shim to the executable during the build process.