# How can I set the compatibility mode for an executable even in all folders?

Tags: windows-10, compatibility

suppose my app to run in compatibility mode is locate on

c:\cats\app.exe

If I manually set the app.exe in compatibility mode (for example WinVistaSP2) with the properties etc.. Windows execute it in compatibility mode WinVistaSP2 only the app.exe locate in c:\cats

But if I move the app.exe in another folder, for example y:\dogs\app.exe the compatibility don't acts in that folder.

So I wonder: is there an app or a tool or a way that keep always and in any folders my preset app.exe in compatibility mode?

Comment: Some reading....https://superuser.com/questions/133746/how-does-the-compatibility-mode-in-windows-work?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is : You cannot.

The compatibility mode is not kept with the file, but rather kept
in the registry under the key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers`.

The application would have an entry of type `REG_SZ` and named
`y:\dogs\app.exe`, having as value all the compatibility flags separated
by a blank. For Vista compatibility you would have `~ VISTARTM`
(note the blank after the `~`).

In addition, these registry entries are never deleted, so the file might be moved
away or replaced, but a file with the same name and in the same folder will always
have these compatibility modes. Not a very sophisticated mechanism, but that's life.

Currently, I don't know of any program that moves the registry entry
when the program is moved, not even Microsoft's file utilities.
You would need to update the registry manually, or write a script that
does the move of the file and also updates the registry.
Windows does not do that.